# handling expo push notifications when app is closed

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo, mobile-development

Expo sdk 37

```
componentDidMount() {
this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
this._notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
}
_handleNotification = notification => {
Vibration.vibrate();
console.log(notification);
console.log(“hello”)
this.setState({ notification: notification });
};
```

When the app is foregrounded the handle function is executed and the console.log is executed but when the app is closed the handle function is not executed at all?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding this in app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light"
    },
    "android": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "dark"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, why does appearence style help to fix push visibility?

Comment: @Kate apparently its an expo bug

Comment: Yeah, I won't receive the `exp.notification` props normally sent to the root component by Expo, unless I apply the settings from this answer.

Comment: Also, once I applied these settings, I can revert them and `exp.notification` will keep on getting received properly.

Comment: The original answer may not be accurate or fully address the question. While it is possible that changing the theme may have resolved the push notification issue, there may be other factors at play. It is essential to thoroughly research and understand a problem before offering a solution and to provide clear and accurate information to assist others in effectively troubleshooting and resolving issues